# Jupyter ipynb file does not open after installing some things to make Download As PDF to HTML work. 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to programming and for a class I had to install Anaconda and Jupyter. I have a homework assignment that is an ipynb file that I was trying to save as a PDF using the Download As PDF from HTML. After being unable to do so, I found resources on StackOverflow to download things like:

```
pip install -U nbconvert==5.6.1 --user
```

... and after doing so and restarting my computer, I go to the open the homework file and it will not open. I simply get `500: Internal Server Error` instantly and I am unable to open the document.

I am sure this has happened before but I was unable to find someone who had the same issue. Thank you in advance.

Restarting computer and researching on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To install nbconvert using Anaconda, you can use the following command:

```
conda install nbconvert
```

For additional documentation on [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/5.6.1/install.html), you can refer to the official documentation https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io.

However, I recommend using [Google Colab](https://colab.google/) for a more seamless and collaborative notebook experience. You can access Google Colab here https://colab.google/.